# Displaying weight suffix next to price on specific products

Tags: opencart

On our products page I need to add `LB` next to the price: `£3.00 / LB`. I've gone into the `catalog/theme/default/template/product/product.tpl` and tried to add the text however no changes seem to appear.

How can I achieve this in OpenCart 2.x

Comment: Why don't you just use a "quick" **vQmod**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to admin panel,
Catelog->Attribute

Here you can find Attribute and Attribute groups add you prodcuct suffix here.

After that go to the product form, in attribute section you can see you new created attribute.Select some suffix and save it.It will show only for that product.

Comment: I'll give it a try when I'm on my lunch today. If this works I will love you forever.

Comment: I've just given it a try, you're right and I would prefer to do it this way, however my client would like it next to the product price, any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: drag the attribute functionality next to the product price.

Comment: Thanks for you advice, I did a check in the product.tpl file, so if it had an attributegroup of 'PerLB' then echo "/ LB" next to the price.